# How to run commands using child process using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, websocket

I have created communication between client and server using socket.io, Now I am sending commands from client to server using WebSockets, I would like to run these received commands from the client on the server

Here is my solution

HTML (client)

```
<html>
<body>
  I am client
</body>
<script>

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9898/');

ws.onopen = function() {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    ws.send('npm run build');
};

ws.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log("Received: '" + e.data + "'");
};

</script>
</html>
```

Here is server.js

```
const http = require('http');
const WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;

const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(9898);

const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

    connection.on('message', function(message) {
      console.log(message.utf8Data);
      connection.sendUTF('Hi this is WebSocket server!');
    });
    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log('Client has disconnected.');
    });
});
```

Now when we run the server and open index.html, the server receives the following message

```
`npm run build`
```

Now how do I run this command on a server using a child process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **child_process** to spawn a new process for your server.js like below

```js
const http = require('http');
const WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(9898);

const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

    connection.on('message', function(message) {
      console.log(message.utf8Data);
      const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(message.utf8Data);
      console.log('stdout:', stdout);
      console.log('stderr:', stderr);
      connection.sendUTF('Hi this is WebSocket server!');
    });
    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log('Client has disconnected.');
    });
});
```